# Durable corded mouse

Tags: mice

I am looking for a durable, corded mouse. I have used the Logitech M500 corded mouse in the past, and I really like the model. Problem is, the thing breaks reliably after less than a year, one way or another. Sometimes the buttons don't work anymore, sometimes that tracking doesn't work or the cable breaks. It's really annoying. I am ordering them at least once a year. My mother also uses this mouse and has the same experience with this model.

I don't need all those fancy features, I just don't want to buy so many mice anymore. Just a sturdy and reliable mouse. Maximum price is 50 bucks, unless you can convince me otherwise =)

We only use them at home, for gaming and other tasks. It would be cool if the size would be comparable to the M500 (not those small laptop mice)

Comment: Why do you keep buying the same product if you have so many issues with it?

Comment: I stopped doing so right now =) I just liked the model and it worked fine until it broke, and I hoped that maybe I was just unlucky with the models, but now it's enough...

Comment: Fair enough. Logitech G series (G502 here) are pretty good as is the Razer Deathadder. Both have served me well.

Comment: I agree with @SiXandSeven8ths here is a [link to buy a Razer Deathadder at 60% discount ($20) (MSRP: $50)](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIAHB07PT6803&cm_re=deathadder-_-9SIAHB07PT6803-_-Product)